# CSS Vertical Navigation Bar

Tags: css, list, button, hyperlink, navigationbar

I am trying to create a vertical navigation bar in CSS.  This is the code I have in my master page:

And this is the code I have in my CSS file:

This is how the menu looks:

[image]

As you can see, the navigation bar does not start exactly from the top of the column.  Moreover, it seems that the margin is not enclosing each button individually, but rather the area covered by all buttons at once.

How can I make the list:

1) start exactly from the top?
2) with the margin around each button and not around the area covered by all the buttons at once?

Thank you.

Comment: do you have a JSFiddle link?

Comment: No, I am using normal CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to `#nav2`

**EDITED:**

apply `vertical-align:top` to `td`

```
td{
   vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but they are still being displayed at the centre of the column vertically :s  In the meantime, I solved the problem I had with the borders by moving the borders from nav2 to nav2 li a

Comment: I will :)  Thanks once again :)

Comment: Thank you :)  Happy coding to you too :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try to set in #nav2 li a  display: inline-block;